# How can I define a metric on a smooth manifold without looking to the space it is embedded in?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, coordinate-systems, spherical-geometry

Consider the sphere, we denote $\psi^{-1}$ as the inverse coordinate chart $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$, by:
$$(\theta,\phi)\mapsto(\cos\theta\sin\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\phi)$$
How can I define a metric on the sphere using this without referring to the ambient space $\mathbb{S}^2$ is embedded in? $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a metric namely $g=d\theta\otimes d\theta+d\phi\otimes d\phi$, but I feel like I can't push this forward to $\mathbb{S}^2$. With a metric defined on $\mathbb{S}^2$ I can pull it back to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I don't see how that helps. I suspect something about working in coordinates is confusing me.

Comment: Have you tried using a partition of unity of argument?

Comment: @Matt I wasn't really worried about partitions of unity, because the chart covers the whole sphere minus a point, and I was more so confused about actually working in coordinates, so wanted to focus on a singular chart.

Comment: If $\psi: \mathbb{S}^2\setminus\{S\}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is a diffeomorphism (i.e., your coordinate map), and $g$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, then the pullback $\psi^*g$ is the metric I believe you're looking to work with.  If $v,w\in T_p\mathbb{S}^2$ with $p\neq S$, you would have $(\psi^*g)_p(v,w)=g_{\psi(p)}(d\psi_p(v),d\psi_p(w))$.

Comment: You certainly can put the flat metric on $S^2$ with two points pulled out. This has nothing to do with the usual round metric.

Comment: @TedShifrin why is the round metric the usual one? and is there anyway to obtain without looking at the space $\mathbb{S}^2$ is embedded in?

Comment: Yes, if you think of the sphere as a homogeneous space, you get either an $SO(3)$- or a $U(2)$-invariant metric (thinking of the sphere as $\Bbb CP^1$). These are both round metrics.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok I see that makes sense, is there any reason this is the usual metric though? Sorry if that's a dumb question.

Comment: Far from a dumb question. The group invariance tells us, in this case, that you’ll get constant curvature (and for topological reasons that must be positive). In the $SO(3)$ case, you can induce it from the $\Bbb R^3$ setting.